# AWS Port 25 issue for sending emails though app hosted on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp

I have a Java Application hosted on `AWS` where I have an `EC2` Instance.
My application generates and sends email to users whenever a new user is registered. This process of sending emails is on halt due to port 25 blocking issue with `AWS`.

Please help me resolving the issue. I found some articles stating that if I create new security group and add ports 465 and 587 but I am not sure it should be inbound or outbound.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you should probably use an external third party managed service for sending emails (and follow their setup instructions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Security Group is stateful and hence once you create an inbound rules, outbound rules will automatically being created. For more information please refer to this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)

> Security groups are stateful — if you send a request from your instance, the response traffic for that request is allowed to flow in regardless of inbound security group rules. Responses to allowed inbound traffic are allowed to flow out, regardless of outbound rules.

Comment: True, but EC2 imposes heavy throttling on outbound traffic with destination port 25 by default.

Answer (score 2):

Ports 465 and 587 are common ports used for SMTP services. It depends on what service you are using. Follow their configuration guide to know which port to use.

If you are providing SMTP service, then you would need to configure your software to listen on port 465 or port 587. Then enable that port in your Security Group Inbound Rule.

If your issue is port 25 being throttled, contact AWS support to have this removed.

This articled will help you:

[How do I remove the throttle on port 25 from my EC2 instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/)

Comment: @WajahatAdil. If my answer solved your problem, why was the other answer selected as the correct answer?